# Redirecting stdout to wxpython TextCtrl from a long running function

Tags: python, wxpython

I inherited a piece of simulation script written in python from a graduate student. It prints its progress onto the terminal every 1s to let us know that it's running, and occasionally some partial summary of the result. Everything works fine.

Then our group decided to make a simple GUI for this script. I have redirected the output to a textctrl class such that the progress can be displayed in the windows instead of staying on the terminal. Below is a very simplified version of what I have written:

```
import threading
import sys
import wx
import time

def LongSimulation(input_):
    # Simulate the behavior of the simulation code that I have
    # Actually it returns more than just the progress
    # Occasionally it also returns some partial summary result for diagnostic
    for i in range(0, 100):
        sys.stdout.write('Progress: %3.0f\r' % float(i))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)
    # return the simulation result
    return 'answer'

def LongSimulationWrapper(q, input_):
    result = LongSimulation(input_)
    q.put(result)

# subclass of TextCtrl. Just to put the flush method back in 
class TextCtrlPipe(wx.TextCtrl):
    def __init__(*args, **kargs):
        wx.TextCtrl.__init__(*args, **kargs)

    def flush(self):
        self.Refresh()


class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)

        # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        style = wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY|wx.HSCROLL

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.log = TextCtrlPipe(panel, wx.ID_ANY, size=(300,100), style=style)
        sizer.Add(self.log, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)

        btn = wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_ANY, 'Start')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton, btn)

        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    def onButton(self, event):
        # redirect output to TextCtrl
        sys.stdout = self.log
        q = queue.Queue()
        # simulation input. I just randomly choose a number to demonstrate
        input_ = 0
        thread = threading.Thread(target=LongSimulationWrapper, args=(q, input_))
        thread.setDaemon(True)
        thread.start()
        # Getting returned result somehow halt the printing of progress
        #print(q.get())

# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

However I immediately ran into some troubles. The problem happens when I tried to use queue to obtain the returned result. If I uncomment the line print(q.get()), then progress no longer appears in real time. Instead everything shows up only after the calculation is finished, which defeated the purpose of a progress bar.

I am aware of the wx.ProgressDialog class. However, it's not just the progress that we needed, but also the partial summary result for diagnostic. We still need to find a way to redirect all the texts. The real 'LongSimulation' is actually quite complicated and I do not fully understand its inner working so I am reluctant to changing any bit of their module. Given such a constraint, what should I do to make it work?

We also have plans for the future to incorporate multiprocessing. The LongSimulation is an embarrassingly parallel simulation (Monte Carlo to be specific) so I can just run the same thing on different processes and merge the results. Let say we are running it on n cores, the idea is to create n TextCtrl, with each of them displaying the progress of each process independently but I cannot get it to work either. I tried to use multiprocessing and passes individual TextCtrl to LongSimulationWrapper for stdout redirection but TextCtrl cannot be pickled. Are there any suggestions that I could work on?

Answers that do not involve changing LongSimulation will be much preferred, but if it's impossible or too difficult to achieve then please tell me what needs to be changed for this to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using python 2.7.9 and wxPython 3.0.1.1 and it is running on linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simplistic approach would be to make use of `wx.GetApp().Yield()` for your posted code.

For the `multiprocessing` approach take a look at the accepted answer here:
[How to capture output of a shell script running in a separate process, in a wxPython TextCtrl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833716/how-to-capture-output-of-a-shell-script-running-in-a-separate-process-in-a-wxpy)

This is the simplistic approach:

```
import wx
import time

def LongSimulation(self,input_):
    # Simulate the behavior of the simulation code that I have
    # Actually it returns more than just the progress
    # Occasionally it also returns some partial summary result for diagnostic
    for i in range(0, 10):
        self.log.write('Progress: %3.0f\r' % float(i))
        time.sleep(1)
        wx.GetApp().Yield()
    return 'answer'

class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)

        # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        style = wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY|wx.HSCROLL

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.log = wx.TextCtrl(panel, wx.ID_ANY, size=(300,100), style=style)
        sizer.Add(self.log, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)

        btn = wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_ANY, 'Start')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton, btn)

        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    def onButton(self, event):
        input_ = 0
        res = LongSimulation(self,input_)
        self.log.write(res)
        self.log.write('\n')

# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes the Yield function works like a charm. The multiprocessing example that you provided also helps a lot. The only problem I have with the multiprocessing example is that the example code creates defunct process. I tried to join all the process at the end but the GUI stops to update in real time. This is not too much of a problem as defunct process don't really hurt me but it would be great if you can explain why can't I join the process and ways to work around it. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I provided the link as an example, I didn't run or test it. In my experience, it is best to never over complicate code. If you plan to change it at a future date, rewrite it in the future, your plans may change. Regards.